What's the difference between crema and sour cream?
Are sour cream (from the US) and crema (from Mexico) the same thing? The place I'm at doesn't have sour cream only crema.




The ingredients in sour cream simply says, "Cultured cream".
The ingredients in crema says, "cow milk's cream 25% fat, citric acid, stabilizers (guar gum, cellulose gum, sodium citrate, carrageenan, mono- and diglycerides, sodium alginate, carob gum, tricalcium phosphate), iodized salt, artificial flavoring, natamicina".
The context is following a recipe calling for sour cream where the closest thing I've found is crema. It has been said they are not the same thing.
Update
I found this article that has been helpful. But the article doesn't say what the ingredients are.
https://www.chilipeppermadness.com/recipes/mexican-crema/

Welcome to the Cooking Stack Exchange. If you could post the ingredients lists of both, that might help. I think from the little I can make out on the Crema, that it is likely artificially thickened and therefore acidified by addition of acid rather than fermentation.

The crema's ingredients are pretty standard additives in dairy products. Nearly all of them and their functions are listed here

You say that you don't have access to normal sour cream, but it's not really difficult to ferment your own, if you have access to sweet cream. You can use normal commercial yogurt as the culture (best to try a brand which advertises a "live" culture).

Can you get (or make) plain yogurt? It's a reasonable substitute for sour cream in some dishes.

I can try yogurt as a substitute

@rumtscho I think the Walmart has sweet cream. Do you have a recipe for making sour cream from sweet cream? I just leave it in the car for 2 days?

@1.21gigawatts certainly not just a random time of sitting in the car! Here is a recipe that describes the process relatively well: https://revolutionfermentation.com/en/blogs/yogurt/how-to-make-yogurt/. It says "yogurt" but if you use sweet cream instead of milk, you'll end up with sour cream. You can use store-bought yogurt for the culture.

They're definitely not the same thing.
If you look at the ingredients, you'll see that the sour cream is, well, sour cream. It's a dairy product (milk cream of a certain fat percentage) that has been fermented.
The crema has not been fermented. Instead, it starts out with cream, and they have added a complex mixture of thickeners to achieve the texture, and some citric acid and flavoring to get the flavor to mimick a cultured product, while not being cultured. You could see it as a substitute for the real thing.
As all highly engineered substitutes, it works as long as it's used in the ways the engineers intended - best straight out of the box. If you try cooking with it, it may or may not work as expected. The taste shouldn't change much no matter what, but the texture may get weird.
It's difficult to predict which cases will work and which won't. Heated recipes are riskier than non-heated ones, but they might still work. Recipes where the result isn't expected to change texture (e.g. if you're making a raita) are more likely to work well, or also recipes where it doesn't matter if the cream suddenly liquefies (e.g. in a pancake batter). But these are really very wild guesses. The only place where you can be sure if it's served as-is, without being mixed with anything or heated. In the end, you have to try each recipe individually and find out if it works or not.

I find Mexican crema typically a little sweeter and not as sour or tangy as sour cream.  In my experience it is also not as thick as sour cream. How it will work as a substitute probably depends on the specific recipe itself.  Consistency could be an issue, but I think it is a reasonable flavor substitute.

I've tried it on cold and hot food and yes it tastes similar. But haven't tried as an ingredient in baked recipes. In my specific case it's in cold food but I have had recipes in hot food.
